# How to display HTML_TEXT as Plain_text in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my application, I am displaying RSS_FEEDS in ListView which contains two Textblocks, one for title and other for description. But in case of description, I am getting Html_text and it is getting displayed as it is. Please suggest how to remove the tags. I have tried using Regular Expressions but it removes tags,but it doesn't remove **nbsp**,
 tags.Also please suggest if there is 
 tag then I want to show that in new line. Please find my code below:

```
private string getplain_text(string p)
    {
        string plain_text = string.Empty;
        plain_text = Regex.Replace(p, "\\<[^\\>]*\\>", string.Empty);
        return plain_text;
    }
```

Awaiting for good responses.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML Agility pack library is good for html document manipulation. You can create document using your html content and plain text getting methods are available there

Comment: Please can you explain with sample code if possible?

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/62772#52179.              Use this method

Comment: Thanks it works great. But can you suggest what can be if I want to show new line for <br/> tag?

Comment: Replace <br/> with \n\r  then  get plain text and then replace them again with <br/>